# macOS Disable mouse acceleration in certain apps

Tags: macos, mouse

Is there a way to disable mouse acceleration in certain apps? For instance disable in Team Fortress 2 but re-anable when the app doesn't have focus?

Answer (score 1):

You can globally use the following command in Terminal (you must log out to take effect):

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1
```

To know what the current acceleration is, use this command:

```
defaults read .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling
```

For most mice in macOS, the default is set to `3` or `2` but some users may find values as low as `0.25` or `0.12`, it generally depends on what type of mouse you are having and the current version of macOS. The moderate value is `0` to `3`.

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling 0
```

Look at this useful AD post: [How to disable mouse acceleration in Yosemite?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151539/how-to-disable-mouse-acceleration-in-yosemite)

Also, for `TF2` game you can definitely use `Apple Automator`: [How to Use Automator in macOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl4y6D5vy44)

> ¡Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this to disable the acceleration in 1 app or system wide? I am looking to disable it in a select apps.

Comment: System wide (globally).

Comment: Ok, is it also possible to disable it in select apps such as Team Fortress 2?

Comment: Try this: http://smoothmouse.com/

Comment: I just know the method to globally turn the acceleration off via Terminal. Don't know the method to disable it for TF2 only. Suppose there's third-party software for this specific performance.

Comment: The links in the smoothmouse website might be useful.

Comment: Also try this: https://github.com/docwhat/killmouseaccel

Comment: Maybe USB Overdrive? [I've never used it so idk]. I use SteerMouse, which is great for everything else, but cannot do cursor speed per app either.

Comment: Suppose "USB Overdrive" is robust solution.